# I encountered an error with winston while running my nestjs backend

Tags: nestjs, typeerror, winston

/platform-backend/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/exception-handler.js:216
transport.once('finish', onDone('finished'));
^

TypeError: transport.once is not a function
at /Volumes/Sans titre 2/Desktop/omedema/platform-backend/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/exception-handler.js:216:17
at /Volumes/Sans titre 2/Desktop/omedema/platform-backend/node_modules/async/internal/withoutIndex.js:8:40
at eachOfArrayLike (/Volumes/Sans titre 2/Desktop/omedema/platform-backend/node_modules/async/eachOf.js:61:9)
at eachOf (/Volumes/Sans titre 2/Desktop/omedema/platform-backend/node_modules/async/eachOf.js:181:12)
at awaitable (/Volumes/Sans titre 2/Desktop/omedema/platform-backend/node_modules/async/internal/awaitify.js:14:28)
at eachLimit (/Volumes/Sans titre 2/Desktop/omedema/platform-backend/node_modules/async/forEach.js:125:33)
at awaitable (/Volumes/Sans titre 2/Desktop/omedema/platform-backend/node_modules/async/internal/awaitify.js:14:28)
at ExceptionHandler._uncaughtException (/Volumes/Sans titre 2/Desktop/omedema/platform-backend/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/exception-handler.js:203:5)
at process.emit (node:events:514:28)
at process.emit (/Volumes/Sans titre 2/Desktop/omedema/platform-backend/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:516:21)

Node.js v18.17.0

i tried to reinstall the winston module, but i got the same error